# How to use STRUCT with FIFO

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, fifo

I'm learning "FIFO" in C this is my first code trying to pass an struct by argument to FIFO function but it's not working as expected... And I can't figure why. Someone could please give me hand an explain what am I doing wrong?

I wrote my code in portuguese if it's hard to you guys understand let me know I'll translate to english.

```
#define TAMANHO 3

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


typedef struct
{
    char Nome[20];
} pretendentes; 



pretendentes // nome da estrutura
pessoas[10]; // vetor de estrutura



int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");


    cadastroPretendentes(pessoas);
    qstore(pessoas);
}

void qstore(pretendentes *Pessoas)
{
    int pfinal   = 0;
    int pinicial = 0;

    if(pinicial == TAMANHO)
    {
        printf("A fila está cheia.");
        return;
    }

    pessoas[pinicial] = Pessoas.Nome;
    pinicial++;
}

void cadastroPretendentes(pretendentes *Pessoas)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++)
    {
        printf("Insira o nome do pretendente %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", (*(Pessoas + i)).nome);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are numerous issues with this code, including that `Possoas` and `pessoas` are different identifiers. Your FIFO implementation is probably not what you want, either; were you trying for a circular buffer? You'd get that by taking the index modulo the array size. And if your FIFO is an array of structures, you would want to copy each structure to it with `memcpy()`. You might want to be sure you're using the data structure you meant to.

Comment: Note that pessoas is global, so you dont need to pass it as a parameter in your main function! Also, observe that pinicial is a local variable and you're losing it's value every time you return from qstore.

Comment: I applied the `gcc` compiler to the posted code.  The result was LOTS of warning and some error messages.  When compiling, always enable the warning, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: @user3629249 I would recommend to use -std=C99 or some other C standard else you might lose portability.

Answer (score 0):

assume that pessoas is fifo memory.

In cadastroPretendentes(), you are getting names and store into fifo memory and in qstore(), you are writing pessoas[0] with pessoas[0].

if qstore is called another 2 times, 1st and 2nd elements in array will be replaced with pessoas[0].

In this code, qstore is not required as cadastroPretendentes() gets name and stores in pessoas (fifo memory)